# What would achieve a O( N/logN) complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sqlite, data-structures, big-o

I was reading [this sqlite documentation](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and came across this quote on their ordered lookup:

> Since the information is stored in the table in rowid order, SQLite can find the correct row using a binary search. If the table contains N elements, the time required to look up the desired row is proportional to logN rather than being proportional to N as in a full table scan. If the table contains 10 million elements, that means the query will be on the order of N/logN or about 1 million times faster.

I've never seen N/logN complexity referenced before. Why would it be N/logN and not logN lookup? A cursory search said its from bucketed ordered segments in an array. Is it because memory limits the size of the binary search segments, at large enough data sets?

If so, how is N/logN calculated? Are there any other real-world applications that use N/logN complexity?

Comment: if I can do one thing in time T1 and another in T2 where T2>T1, then doing first thing is T2/T1 times faster than doing the other.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I got hung up on the wording. Thanks! 

Still though, I'm curious if there are any real-world examples of N/logN complexity.

Comment: No examples offhand, but the number of primes up to `N` is `O(N log(N))`.

Comment: You're reading it wrong.  It doesn't say that the complexity is O(N/log N), it says that binary search is N/logN = 1000000 *times faster* than table scan.

Answer (score 1):

One source of O(n/log n) running times is bit parallelism in a machine model with constant-time operations on (log n)-bit words (the unit-cost random access machine). An n-bit bitmap takes O(n/log n) words, so union, intersection, difference, etc. all would take time O(n/log n).

Answer (score 0):

The text says 1 million times *faster*. They mean a ratio, not a complexity.